# Saving new records in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Since I didn't get any replies in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179143/problem-saving-new-records-to-multiple-tables-from-a-single-view) I will try to ask a more general one.

I have a table and class like that:

```
PK TeamID int;
FK CountryID int;
   Name string
   ......
```

In my Create View I have textboxes for the Team table properties and a dropdown list of countries which is populated with values from another DB table.

The problem I am having is that I can't save new records because ModelState.IsValid always fails. Could someone help me with writing the POST Create method? I am using MVC 2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please debug the action, and see what Model errors are generated. Probably one field is not setup right ie. named differently then whats expected in model. Check your previous question also.

Comment: @zveljkovic Seems that the solution is always the simplest one. I indeed had a mispelled field in my view. Took me 2 days to find it. Thanks a lot for making me look there for the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the validation in your view is failing for some reason. Have you checked for any javascript errors when you press submit? Firefox with firebug addon is handy for troubleshooting such things.